# how to use MnSymbol along with other packages

Tags: fonts, symbols, packages

I'm writing a file about algebraic topology, which means that I need all sorts of mathematical symbols, along with many various packages. I tried to use `MnSymbol` for its various arrows, only to find out that it is incompatible with `amssymb` and `amsfonts`.

Cutting out those two packages introduces new problems: `\mathbb{..}` doesn't work.

How is a mathematician supposed to use MnSymbol?

Currently, I am using the following packages:
`etex`, `babel`, `inputenc`, `fontenc`, `charter`, `MnSymbol`, `amsmath`, `ntheorem`, `framed`, `tikz`, `bookmark`, `hyperref`, `xy`, `mathtools`, `graphicx`, `animate`, `color`, `subfigure`, `caption`, `verbatim`, `multirow`, `longtable`, `wrapfig`, `cancel`, `enumitem`, `tocloft`, `geometry`, `stmaryrd`, `ulem`, `titlesec`, `fix-cm`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`MnSymbol` is indeed imcompatible with `amssymb` and `amsfonts`. To use the AMS blackboard font in conjunction with `MnSymbol`, you can add the following to the preamble of your document:

`\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathbb{U}{msb}{m}{n}`

By the way, which symbol do you use from `stmaryrd`? If there is a similar symbol in `MnSymbol`, I would suggest to use that one for more consistency.

Comment: From `stmaryrd`, I'm using blackboard braces [...]. I see, that MnSymbol also includes them, so thanks for a good suggestion.

Comment: I have a REQUEST: I'm using $\ssearrow$ to denote a deformation retraction. I wanted to use the same arrow, but with two heads for a strong deformation retraction. It doesn't exist, even in MnSymbol. Would you be so kind to write me a command \newcommand{\twoheadssearrow}[0]{...}, which adds to \ssearrow another head. I would be really really grateful (I have no idea how to do it). Should I make a new thread for this? This is the only thing I was looking for in MnSymbol, and now I see it isn't included in the package.

Comment: You mean a double-headed version `\sesearrow`? Indeed, I think it is best if you pose a new question for this.